# Can't compile cx_Freeze on a Python built from source

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, package, cx-freeze

Here's my situation.  I'm trying to package a game for Linux (on Ubuntu 13.04) written in Python 3.3 via `cx_Freeze`.  Fine.  I installed it via `sudo apt-get install cx-freeze`.  Even though it installed, it didn't show up.  So it's the Python 2 version.  Fine.  I then downloaded the source code from the website and tried to compile it with `python3 ./setup.py build`.  This is where things fall apart.  I get this error from the compiler:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm using Python 3.3.2, which I compiled from source.  Any tips?

Comment: You'll need to have built Python with a shared library (this is how it is in the distro packages). If you install `python3` and `python3-dev` in Ubuntu, it should work.

Comment: I have them installed already, though.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of using those instead of your own compiled version. Is it important to use Python compiled from source? If so, you'll need to find a flag to compile it with a shared library, because I don't think that's the default.

Comment: No, it's not necessary.  I just built from source because I wanted to compile it with `-Ofast` rather than `-O3` (I think) as the deb is.  I'm not sure which deb I have installed, though (dunno if Python 3.3.2 is the default in Ubuntu 13.04 or not).

Comment: Raring has 3.3.1 at the moment - you can check [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python3).

Comment: It looks like the compilation flag is called `--enable-shared`.

Comment: What does that flag do, and where does it go?  It's not in the `gcc` docs.

Comment: It's not a gcc flag, it's a specific option for compiling Python. You give it to `./configure`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  (I'm not very familiar with build systems of large projects.  Anything beyond `./configure; sudo make install` brings me to this site.)  I'll give it a shot when I get home from work.

Comment: It worked!  You da man.  Can you please post it as a legit answer so I can give you the rep you deserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

In general, I'd recommend using the Python packages from your distribution, which are already compiled in a way that cx_Freeze can work with. In Ubuntu, you can install `python3` and `python3-dev`.

If you need to compile your own Python interpreter, then you'll need to compile it with a shared library, like this:

```
./configure --enable-shared
```

There are more instructions on compiling in the [CPython devguide](http://docs.python.org/devguide/).